# DNN 9.1 upgrade error - Method not found: 'Int32 Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile.get_ContentLength()'

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have recently upgrade my dnn from 5.0 version to 9.1 version with suggested upgrade on below URL:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/suggested-upgrade-path

The upgrade went smoothly but one issue I am getting is in file upload. I am getting below error:

> Method not found: 'Int32
>   Telerik.Web.UI.UploadedFile.get_ContentLength()'

Please see below screenshot:
[image]

I have tried to search google for this but not able to get appropriate solution. can you please suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

I would change to the default DNN9 editor in the web.config file so Telerik is no longer in use, but CKEditor is used instead.

`<htmlEditor defaultProvider="DNNConnect.CKE">`

I feel like there is a Telerik.Web.UI.dll version conflict in the bin folder which is causing it.